# How do you cross rivers in AC: New Horizons?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Having just started a new game, some areas of my island are inaccessible, blocked by rivers I cannot cross. I assume eventually I will be able to construct bridges, but can I use anything else before then?

What are all the ways I can use to get on the other side of rivers, and are any of them permanent? Additionally, how can I unlock them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first way is to use the **Vaulting Pole**.

> This is from [Blathers in the museum](https://www.polygon.com/animal-crossing-new-horizons-switch-acnh-guide/2020/3/20/21182290/first-week-daily-goals-how-to-unlock-museum-steps-farming#qPlD9M) after you give him 15 donations (20 total). He only shows up after providing Tom Nook with the first five of those fauna.

You can also build **bridges**.

> After [Resident Services is upgraded](https://twinfinite.net/2020/03/animal-crossing-new-horizons-build-bridges/) from its tent form, you can build infrastructure. Bridge options include wood, iron, brick, suspension. And then you choose where it's built.